# Fancybox (on Wordpress) Next and Previous buttons

Tags: wordpress, fancybox

I am using the Fancybox script on my Wordpress website to display my portfolio.  Here is how it is setup:

Users go to my archive-portfolio page where they can see all my works.  When they click on one of our portfolio items, instead of it taking you to a single-post page it simply shows the single-post info in a fancybox for the item they clicked.

All of that works great but I would like to implement a Previous and Next arrow for them to navigate between works while that fancybox is displayed.

I thought I could get away with using the built in WP function of Next and previous in the loop like so:

```
<?php previous_post(); ?>    <?php next_post(); ?>
```

But that does not work and I am guessing is because the single-post page is never actually displayed.

Anyways [here is a link I found on the callbacks for it](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/143/#issuecomment-7278978)  but my JS skills are next to none.

and finally here is what my archive template looks like and how I am using it.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

              <?php $counter = 1 ?>

          <!-- START LOOP -->
          <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                      <div class="three columns portfolio-piece">
                          <a href="#more-info<?php echo $counter ?>" class="fancybox">

                              <?php 
                                  if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                      the_post_thumbnail( 'custom-archive-size' );
                                  } else {
                                      echo 'No Preview Available'; 
                                  } 
                              ?>

                          <div class="cover boxcaption"><?php echo the_title(); ?></div>
                          </a>
                      </div>

                      <div id="more-info<?php echo $counter ?>" style="display:none;width:auto;">
                          <div class="twelve columns">

                              <div class="four columns portfolio-image">
                           <?php 
                                  if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                      the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );
                                  } else {
                                      echo 'No Preview Available'; 
                                  } 
                              ?>
                              </div>

                              <div class="eight columns portfolio-listing" style="max-width:720px !important;">

                                <h3 class="portfolio-heading" ><?php the_title() ?></h3>
                                <p><?php the_content() ?></p>

                                  <strong>Website: </strong>
                      <a href="<?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_website', true ) ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_website', true ) ); ?></a></strong>
                              </div>

                          </div>

                     </div><!-- more info -->

                      <?php if ($counter % 4 == 0){echo '</div><div class="twelve columns" style="margin:15px 0;">';} ?>

                     <?php $counter++ ?>

          <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated :)  Thanks

Comment: `they can see all my works. When they click on one of our portfolio items it shows the single-post info in a fancybox` ... then add the same `rel` attribute to the links to your different posts and you will be able to navigate through them

Comment: Wondering if there is a way for me to just add an anchor within that loop similar to this to achieve the result I need:

'<a href="#more-info<?php ++$counter ?>" title="Next Item">Next</a>'

Comment: Thanks JFK, since that is in my loop and I am using a counter all of the posts shown on the page have the same rel and href but the numbers appended to #more-info changes.  So I need a way to add one to more info when clicking next and subtract one when clicking previous to navigate between.  Like your viewing #more-info12 and clicking next would take you to #more-info13 and vice versa for previous.

Comment: Tried adding the rel="Gallery" to my anchor tag and adding this http://jsfiddle.net/xW5gs/ to my JS file and no luck :(

Comment: Ok I actually have two sites that use the fancybox, one of them I was able to use JFK's advice by adding the rel="gallery" and it worked perfectly.  The other site (the one I originally posted about) it does not work but I see there are some JS errors which could be causing the issue?  See here: http://designloud.com/portfolios_categories/web-design/

The next and previous show in the HTML but dont actually show up when fancybox is loaded?

Comment: Your fancybox js file is v2.1.4 while your fancybox css file is v2.1.5 ... try using the same version for both

Comment: Regarding your js errors, you may have a hoisting issue. Try loading jQuery before any other plugin that have dependency of it (in other words, move your jQuery call to the top of your scripts in your `<head>` section)

Comment: Ok, because I have enqueued my scripts should I just move the wp_head section to the top after declaring the head?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was in my stylesheet, I had a z-index on the fancy box-wrap because of some issues with my select box but by removing that the arrows actually did show up.